# Using position in one list to read in file from another list in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, vector

I have a vector of city names called `cities`:

```
> cities
[1] 'amsterdam' 'atlanta' 'bangalore'
[4] 'bogota' 'boston' 'brisbane'
[7] 'brussels' 'cairo' 'cape'
```

I have two folders where the same cities are present and ordered in the same way. I have turned each folder into a list. Each file in `list1` contains geographic data for one city. Each file in `list2` contains travel time data for one city.

```
> list1
[[1]]
[1] "C:/geo/amsterdam.json"
[[2]]
[1] "C:/geo/atlanta.json"
[[3]]
[1] "C:/geo/bangalore.json"

> list2
[[1]]
[1] "C:/time/amsterdam.csv"
[[2]]
[1] "C:/time/atlanta.csv"
[[3]]
[1] "C:/time/bangalore.csv"
```

I would like to write a loop that,

- Based on the position of the city in `cities`,
- reads in the corresponding file from `list1`,
- reads in the corresponding file from `list2`,
- merges the two datasets together into a dataset whose name corresponds to the index position in `cities`

Something like that:

```
for (i in length(cities)){
geo <- (sf::st_read(list1[i])
time <- (data.table::fread(list2[i])
merged[i] <- merge(geo, time, by='id') #both datasets have an 'id' column
}
```

Currently, this loop gives the error `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`. 
When I try indexing each output (i.e. `geo[i] <- (sf::st_read(list1[i])`...), I get the error `new columns would leave holes after existing columns`.

Is there a way to carry out operations on elements of a list based on the position of these elements (or their equivalent) in another list/vector?

Comment: Without having some of the files to reproduce my best advice is using `dplyr::inner_join()` with something like:
`merged <- list();
for (i in 1:length(cities)){
      geo <- (sf::st_read(list1[i]));
      time <- (data.table::fread(list2[i]));
      merged[[i]} <- dplyr::inner_join(geo, time, by='id') 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to initialise, before the loop, an empty list which will receive the `merged` dataframes:

```
merged=list()

for (i in length(cities)){
    geo <- (sf::st_read(list1[i])
    time <- (data.table::fread(list2[i])
    merged[i] <- merge(geo, time, by='id') #both datasets have an 'id' column
}
```